# Fast way to search in the List<String> in Android

Tags: java, android, algorithm, search, full-text-search

### Problem Description

---

I have list of strings, which contains 8000 items. Items which contains list are described below.

```
List<String> stringList = new List<String>(8000);
stringList.add("this is first string.");
stringList.add("text which I want to search.");
stringList.add("separated string items.");
....
```

So you can see that every item in my list is a sentence which have more then three words.

### Question.

---

User from outside can search through the list in the following way. For example user want to search word "**first**" the search algorithm must work in this way.

Search algorithm must run over the list and compare word "**first**" with all words in the sentence and if any word in the sentence starts with "**first**" it must return that sentence  ". So in order to realize this algorithm I write following code, you can see code below.

**Algorithm which I implement works very slow, So I want to know if there is faster algorithm or how I can made my algorithm faster ?**

### Code Example

---

```
Iterator<ContactInformation> stringListIter  = stringList .iterator();
while (stringListIter.hasNext()) {
            
    String currItem = stringListIter.next();
    String[] separatedStr = currItem.split(" ");

    for(int i=0; i<separatedStr.lenght; ++i)
        if(separatedStr[i].startsWith(textToFind))
            retList.add(currItem);  
}
```

Comment: That's a lot of data to be stored in an in-memory data structure. Why don't you use a database?

Comment: @Rajesh An Sqlite database ?

Comment: Yes, an [SQLite database](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#db)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the [`String#contains`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains%28java.lang.CharSequence%29) method along with [`String#startsWith`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#startsWith%28java.lang.String%29)instead of splitting your `String` and searching each token.

```
String currItem = stringListIter.next();
if(currItem.startsWith(textToFind.concat(space))){
    retList.add(currItem);
} else if(currItem.endsWith(space.concat(textToFind))){
    retList.add(currItem);
} else if(currItem.contains(space.concat(textToFind).concat(space))){
    retList.add(currItem);
} else if(currItem.equals(textToFind)){
    retList.add(currItem);
}
```

First `if` - Checks if its the first word.

Second `if` - Checks if its the last word.

Third `if` - Checks if its somewhere in the middle.

Last `if` - Checks if its the only word.

Comment: Contains is not work in a same way like start with, `if(currItem.contains(textToFind))` this work fast, but this is not my case.

Comment: @ViToBrothers - Check the update! I hope it solves your problem. You can use a `regex` too, but I'm not an expert in `regex`, so you need to ask help elsewhere, in that case!

Answer (score 2):

I would hold a `Map<String, Set<Integer>>` where every word is a key and the value are the indexes of the sentence that contains this word.

Answer (score 1):

A task perfectly suited for [Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/core/).

Answer (score 1):

```
for(String s : yourList){
    if(s.contains(textToFind)){
        retList.add(s);
    }
}
```